# How to use 'ref' at compile time?

Tags: d

```
struct Matrix(int row, int col){ /* ... */ }

// finds the inverse using Gauss–Jordan elimination
pure M inverse(M)(const ref M m){ /* ... */ }
```

The reason `m` is a `ref` is because of performance.  Obviously, I don't want large matrices being copied around every time the inverse is needed, and this has worked fine so far.

But, it has become a problem in situations where the inverse is needed at compile time:

```
mixin template A(){

  alias Matrix!(3, 3) Matrix3x3;

  static Matrix3x3 computeSomeMatrix(){ }

  immutable Matrix3x3 _m = computeSomeMatrix();
  immutable Matrix3x3 _m_1 = inverse(computeSomeMatrix());  // error
}
```

To fix the error, I need to change `m` to a non-ref, but that means that matrices will be copied every time `inverse()` is called.  What do I do?

Comment: Or just simply have both ref and non-ref `inverse()` variants?

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? `ref` should work at compile time, it's probably something else you're doing that's causing it.

Comment: @Robert The error says that `computeSomeMatrix()` is not an lvalue.

Comment: @CyberShadow hmm... `inverse(M)(auto const ref M m){ }` worked.  Care to explain?

Comment: @DejanLekic That's just code duplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see one of two options. One, create a version which takes an rvalue. It's frequently annoying when a function doesn't work with rvalues anyway. A simple wrapper is all you need:

```
pure M inverse(M)(const ref M m){ /* ... */ }
pure M inverse(M)(const M m){ inverse(m); }
```

Be careful that the const-ness of the parameters matches though, or you're going to get infinite recursion.

However, a better solution would be to use `auto ref`. This is what it was created for.

```
pure M inverse(M)(const auto ref M m){ /* ... */ }
```

The compiler will then use `ref` when appropriate and non-`ref` when appropriate without you having to worry about it.